# Difference between !! and ! in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have encountered those operators that are checking for `user.rank` property:

```
<div ng-show="!!user.rank">
    {{user.rank}}
</div>
<button ng-show="!user.rank"  ng-click="addRank(user)">Add Rank</button>
```

How are they different and what can we use instead?

Comment: `!!` converts target to `boolean` type.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

A single bang (`!`) is used to negate a boolean.

Double bang (`!!`) is used to coerce a truthy/falsey value to a boolean true or false.

for example

```js
var x = 0; // a falsey value
console.log(x); // logs 0
console.log(!x)// logs true
console.log(!!x)// logs false

var y = "Hello world"; // a truthy value
console.log(y); // logs "Hello world"
console.log(!y)// logs false
console.log(!!y)// logs true
```

Applied to your specific case

```
ng-show="!!user.rank"
```

`ng-show` is no doubt expecting an actual boolean, and `user.rank` is obviously either truthy or falsey - coercing it to a boolean satisfies your angular directive appropriately.

Comment: you can coerce a boolean to its invert value using !!! and to its normal value using !!!! and so on, hahahah

Answer (score -1):

[What is the !! (not not) operator in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/784929/what-is-the-not-not-operator-in-javascript)

*From the JS wiki on SO*

**Regarding !!**:

> "Coerces oObject to boolean. If it was falsey (e.g. 0, null, undefined, etc.), it will be false, otherwise, true."
>
> "It converts a nonboolean to an inverted boolean (for instance, !5 would be false, since 5 is a non-false value in JS), then boolean-inverts that so you get the original value as a boolean (so !!5 would be true)"
>
> **"So !! is not an operator, it's just the ! operator twice."**